# WCF, Exception: NetTcpPortSharing service: the service failed to listen. When services running

Tags: c#, wcf, service

При запуске приложения WCF возникает ошибка:
System.ServiceModel.AddressAlreadyInUseException: The TransportManager failed to listen on the supplied URI using the NetTcpPortSharing service: the service failed to listen.
При попитке найти ответ в интернете, все говорят включить червис NetTcpPortSharing services[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но как видно на скриншоте, то он уже запущен, Startup Type  пробовал устанавливать как Automatic так и Manual и запускал непосредственно перд запуском приложения, ничего это не дало.

Подскажите какие могут быть пути решения?

Заранее большое спасибо!

Comment: _какие могут быть пути решения_ - ASP.NET Core

Comment: Какую версию .NET используете? / Гляньте [это](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/dotnet/wcf/service-throws-exception) и [это](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21865893/5045688).